# Pass field content as variable from block preprocessor to block tpl

Tags: drupal, preprocessor, field

I have a preprocess function:

```
[MYTHEMENAME]_theme_preprocess_views_view_fields__random_quote__block(&$vars)
```

and then a template file to render the variables:

```
views-view--random_quote--block.tpl.php
```

I can easily set a variable like so:

```
$vars['bam'] = 'whatever';
```

and display that in my template file. Now my question is, how do I pass the contents of a field to my template? Something like:

```
$vars['customer_name'] = 'field_customer_name';
```

Where 'field_customer_name' is a field in the content type. I have tried using the field api and I am getting nowhere. My view is getting that field and I can see the data in the preview of the view content

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't figure out how to do this, but I ended up using a fields tpl (in this case: views-view-fields--random_quote.tpl.php) so I could format each field like so

```
<cite><b><?php print strip_tags($fields['field_customer_name']->content); ?></b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to do it!

```
$entity = $vars['view']->result[0]->_field_data['nid']['entity'];
$vars['customer_name'] = '$entity->field_customer_name[$entity->language][0]['value'];
```

Hope this helps someone